# Variable x no definida

Tags: javascript, html

Estaba haciendo un programa que en un formulario vos colocás un número y otro número y estos se multiplican, y el resultado se muestra en una tabla. Antes ya había hecho algo parecido con la variable x, pero ahora me sale que la variable x no está definida, cuando esta ya está definida de antes; además, la parte del programa que usa la variable x está comentada porque estaba viendo parte por parte para ver si funcionaba y qué fallaba. He aquí el código:

```
let multi = () => {

        let num1 = parseInt(document.form.num1.value);
        let num2 = parseInt(document.form.num2.value);
        console.log(num1);
        console.log(num2);

        let result,x;
        x = "<table>";
        
        for (i=1;i<=num2;i++) {
            console.log("Funciono");
            let e = i;
            console.log(e);
            result = num1 * e;
            console.log(`${num1} x ${e} = ${result}`);

            for(j = 0;j <= 1; j++ ) {
                console.log("Funciono 2");
                /*
                x = x + "<tr>";
                x = x + `<th> ${num1} x ${e}</th>`;
                    h = 0;                  
                x = x + `<th>=</th>`;
                    x = x + `<th>${result}</th>`;
                x = x +`</tr>`;
                }*/
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = x;
```

El código resuelto es:

```
    let multi = () => {

        let num1 = parseInt(document.form.num1.value);
        let num2 = parseInt(document.form.num2.value);
        console.log(num1);
        console.log(num2);

        let result,x;
        x = "<table>";
        
        for (i=1;i<=num2;i++) {
            console.log("Funciono");
            let e = i;
            console.log(e);
            result = num1 * e;
            console.log(`${num1} x ${e} = ${result}`);

            for(j = 0;j <= 0; j++ ) {
                console.log("Funciono 2");
                x = x + "<tr>";
                x = x + `<th> ${num1} x ${e}</th>`;
                x = x + `<th>=</th>`;
                x = x + `<th>${result}</th>`;
                x = x +`</tr>`;
                
                }
            }
        document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = x;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mueve la línea `document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = x;` hacia arriba. Si te fijas está fuera de la función `multi` que defines en la línea 6. Quedará de esta forma:

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Ejercicio 62</title>
    <script>
    let multi = () => {

        let num1 = parseInt(document.form.num1.value);
        let num2 = parseInt(document.form.num2.value);
        console.log(num1);
        console.log(num2);

        let result,x;
        x = "<table>";
        
        for (i=1;i<=num2;i++) {
            console.log("Funciono");
            let e = i;
            console.log(e);
            result = num1 * e;
            console.log(`${num1} x ${e} = ${result}`);

            for(j = 0;j <= 1; j++ ) {
                console.log("Funciono 2");
                x = x + "<tr>";
                
                x = x + `<th> ${num1} x ${e}</th>`;
                    h = 0;                  
                
                
                
                x = x + `<th>=</th>`;
                    
                
                
                    x = x + `<th>${result}</th>`;

                
                x = x +`</tr>`;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = x;
        }
        
        
    


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Multiplicación</h1>
    <form name="form">
        <label>Número 1:</label>
        <input type="number" name="num1">
        <label>Número 2:</label>
        <input type="number" name="num2">
        <input type="button" name="datos" value="multiplicar" onclick="multi()">
    </form>
    <div id="contenedor">
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me habre equivacado haciendo otros for pero gracias.